# Without using the Space Hierarchy Theorm is there any other way to prove that NL is not equal to PSPACE

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

From what I know there is no alternate way  that NL is not equal to PSPACE. If possible can you link a paper or some book recommendations to show that this is the case.
Thank You
Akash